# How to randomize published date for WordPress custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, date

I have tried the following answer to randomize post published date:
[Update existing post dates to random dates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259750/update-existing-post-dates-to-random-dates)

It worked but I need to randomize custom post type. How do I do that?
Example: post_type=portfolio

Thank you!

Comment: `$posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_type' => 'portfolio' ) );` ?

Comment: @kero can you post answers as answers? Comments are for clarifying questions

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the argument `post_type` for the function [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) (see [all available arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) here). So this line

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any' ) );
```

will become this line

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_type' => 'portfolio' ) );
```