# Update all comments time to random dates?

Tags: posts, comments, date, timestamp

I found this code snippet which randomly changes all the dates for all posts.  (Original Post : [Update existing post dates to random dates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259750/update-existing-post-dates-to-random-dates) )

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 259750 Random Dates
 * Description: On activation, change the dates of all posts to random dates
 */

//* We want to do this only once, so add hook to plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'wpse_259750_activation' );
function wpse_259750_activation() {

  //* Get all the posts
  $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any' ) );
  foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    //* Generate a random date between January 1st, 2015 and now
    $random_date = mt_rand( strtotime( '1 January 2015' ), time() );
    $date_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    //* Format the date that WordPress likes
    $post_date = date( $date_format, $random_date );

    //* We only want to update the post date
    $update = array(
      'ID' => $post->ID,
      'post_date' => $post_date,
      'post_date_gmt' => null,
    );

    //* Update the post
    wp_update_post( $update );
  }
}
```

I tried editing it & changing the function to fetch comments & edit them for my woocommerce reviews / comments but it doesn't seem to work? Any tweak that would help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want Virtual Reviews. Actually you can call it fake reviews. Or just you want to change your existing reviews date? If you want fake reviews for your woocommerce then you can use this plugin. [WooCommerce Virtual Review Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-virtual-reviews/)