# Update existing post dates to random dates and time

Tags: plugins, posts, date

I found this solution but it's now not working now (I am getting a fatal error), can anyone please update the code so its works with WordPress 6.1 (Original Post: [Update existing post dates to random dates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259750/update-existing-post-dates-to-random-dates))

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 259750 Random Dates
 * Description: On activation, change the dates of all posts to random dates
 */

//* We want to do this only once, so add hook to plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'wpse_259750_activation' );
function wpse_259750_activation() {

  //* Get all the posts
  $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any' ) );
  foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    //* Generate a random date between January 1st, 2015 and now
    $random_date = mt_rand( strtotime( '1 January 2015' ), time() );
    $date_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    //* Format the date that WordPress likes
    $post_date = date( $date_format, $random_date );

    //* We only want to update the post date
    $update = array(
      'ID' => $post->ID,
      'post_date' => $post_date,
      'post_date_gmt' => null,
    );

    //* Update the post
    wp_update_post( $update );
  }
}
```

I have a huge amount of posts, I think in this code trying to pull all posts at a time so if possible maybe we can add a batch system?

Comment: I don't see anything here that would be affected by any WordPress changes since it was written. What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, @JacobPeattie when I am activating WordPress just showing fatal error, no description. Maybe this plugin trying to pull all posts same time, if we can give a limit then maybe it will work.

Comment: @JacobPeattie do you know any CLI way to do samething?

Comment: Yes, this will crash your site if you have a lot of posts. Using a WP CLI custom command is a good idea. You can use the same function as the callback to `WP_CLI::add_command`